# Authentication with oauth2 on soundcloud api

Tags: android, http, soundcloud

I'm trying to get logged in soundcloud by using their API. I manage to got a code with a success response from [/connect](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#connect) but when I try to get a [token](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#token), I end up with a 401 error. Here is what I send :

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.soundcloud.com
Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 255c7769-0f65-5c40-27bc-9429ea8c38ea

client_id=<my client id>&
client_secret=<my secret id>&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=a99cfc85c0e46235d7fdb9ca74b7dddd%23
```

Does anyone knows what I miss here to get a working request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I was not calling /connect correctly, this is the correct way :

```
https://soundcloud.com/connect?
client_id=<my client id>
&redirect_uri=<my redirect url>
&response_type=token
&scope=non-expiring
&display=popup
```

With `response_type=token`, we directly receive an access token so we don't need to call `/oauth2/token` then.